pasar de un tipo de grafico a otro Chart.js
estoy haciendo una pagina mas o menos dinamica que muestra graficos, quiero que al seleccionar desde un select un tipo de grafico (bar, line, pie, etc) pues se refresque el canvas donde lo tengo, la cosa es que note que al cambiar se quedaban partes del anterior grafico (ejemplo pasar de un grafico de Radar a lineas )

como ven se muestra el pentagono del grafico de Radar en el de Lineas, y quiero evitar eso, adjunto el code de la funcion change del select
var selectTipoGrafico = document.getElementById('tipoGrafico'); /

selectTipoGrafico.addEventListener('change', function () {

var tipoGrafico = selectTipoGrafico.value;
if (tipoGrafico === 'bar' || tipoGrafico === 'line' || tipoGrafico 
=== 'radar')  {
    document.getElementById('Seleccion_DeDatas').style.display = 
'none';
} else {
    document.getElementById('Seleccion_DeDatas').style.display = 
'block';
}

myChart.config.type = tipoGrafico;
myChart.update();

});

el de mi configuracion de chart
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'bar',
data: {
    labels: arreglosSeparados.nombre,
    datasets: []
},
options: {
    responsive: true,
    plugins: {
        legend: {
            labels: {

            },

            position: 'top',

        },
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: dataGeneral[0].tituloGrafico
        }
    },
    scales: {
        y: {
         // stacked: true
        }
      }
}
});

mi elemento html
 <div id="contenedor_delChart" class="verbor chart-container pb-4 d-flex justify- 
  content-center">
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>


Favor agregar un [MCVE] en el snippet con datos de ejemplo

como puedo ser mas claro?

Si lo generas al mismo tiempo puedes ocultar o visualizarlo con CSS con display block o none

@RokenbúPolecat Mira esta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/618200/301324, observa que hay un botón "Ejecutar" en el código (porque se hace uso del snippet, el icono que tiene <>), esto permite apreciar el problema directamente
